# Convert object to array to introduce into foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have this object:

```
var paises = {
        pais: [
            {
                idPais: "1",
                nombre: "España",
                continente: "Europa",
            },
            {
                idPais: "2",
                nombre: "Portugal",
                continente: "Europa",
            },
            {
                idPais: "3",
                nombre: "Francia",
                continente: "Europa",
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to array and get the object's atributes this way:

```
function getCountries(continente){
    var proceed=true;
    var formA = "<select name='selectPais'>"
    var formB = "</select>"
    var arrayPaises = $.map(paises, function(value, index){
        return [value].nombre;
    });
    console.log(arrayPaises);
    arrayPaises.forEach(
            function (item,index){
                formA = formA + "<option value="+item[index].nombre+"id="+item[index].idPais+">";
            }
    );
    var formDiv = document.getElementById("formDiv");
    formDiv.innerHTML = formA+formB;

}
```

The console log shows an empty string as result. I have tried with `return [value];` and it returns an 3 elements (countries) with 2 "objects" each one, like this:

[image]

How can I get the object atributes to transform in array to able to introduce into foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error will come from `item[index]`, you don't need the index in a forEach, every loop already holds what you expect by using `[index]`.

However, that's not really the way you would do that (string concatenation, multiple unnecessary loops, setting innerHTML). Also paises.pais already is an array which you can directly loop.

Instead, create elements with the appropriate methods, see below:

```js
var paises = {
  pais: [{
    idPais: "1",
    nombre: "España",
    continente: "Europa",
  }, {
    idPais: "2",
    nombre: "Portugal",
    continente: "Europa",
  }, {
    idPais: "3",
    nombre: "Francia",
    continente: "Europa",
  }]
};

function createSelection(arr, appendToDiv) {
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.name = "selectPais";
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.id = item.idPais;
    option.value = item.nombre
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.nombre));
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  document.getElementById(appendToDiv).appendChild(select);
}

createSelection(paises.pais, "form-div");
```

```html
<div id="form-div">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! I think is the best way to do this and did not thought on it. Thanks.

Comment: How could i get elements if "pais" is not a string, is a number: like here https://jsfiddle.net/021mpopc/

Comment: Use bracket notation. item[number] @Asier

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working function.

Parse JSON as `paises.pais.forEach();`

And there are `string` concatenation mistakes in your code for making `HTML` with `js`.

```js
var paises = {
        pais: [
            {
                idPais: "1",
                nombre: "España",
                continente: "Europa",
            },
            {
                idPais: "2",
                nombre: "Portugal",
                continente: "Europa",
            },
            {
                idPais: "3",
                nombre: "Francia",
                continente: "Europa",
            }
        ]
};
function getCountries(continente){
    var proceed=true;
    var formA = "<select name='selectPais'>"
    var formB = "</select>"
    paises.pais.forEach(
            function (item,index){
                formA = formA + "<option value='"+item.nombre+"' id='" + item.idPais + "'>" + item.nombre + "</option>";
            }
    );
    var formDiv = document.getElementById("formDiv");
    formDiv.innerHTML = formA+formB;

}
getCountries();
```

```html
<div id="formDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are using JQuery, why not use it all the way? The code stays cleaner and you don't have to use 'mixed' ways to achieve the results you are looking for.

Here's a link to JSFiddle showing one way to do the thing you want to.

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7891/

```
var paises = {
  pais: [
  {
    idPais: "1",
    nombre: "España",
    continente: "Europa",
  },
  {
    idPais: "2",
    nombre: "Portugal",
    continente: "Europa",
  },
  {
    idPais: "3",
    nombre: "Francia",
    continente: "Europa",
  }
  ]
}


function getCountries(continente){
  var select = $("<select name='selectPais' />");

  paises.pais.forEach(function(item,index) {
    var opt = $("<option />");
    opt.attr("value",item.nombre);
    opt.attr("id",item.id);
    opt.text(item.nombre);
    select.append(opt);
  });
  $("#formDiv").append(select);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  getCountries();
});
```